# I dont't understand a proof for the second-order condition for convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

I find a proof [here]
(http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-math-topics/129503-second-order-condition-convexity.html).
But I don't understand the second part. For example, what does it mean to say

> For the converse, if f is convex, then certain subdeterminants of the
> Hessian matrix satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with some of the terms? Are you not sure what conditions are being talked about? Where is it you are stuck?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I don't know what the two 'certain' in the sentence mean.@AlexBecker

Answer (score 0):

The second part is hard to understand because it is basically a tautology; I would not consider it a valid proof. The "certain conditions" they're talking about *is* the positive-definiteness of the Hessian.

Another reference is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799786/does-the-positive-semidefiniteness-of-a-function-not-necessarily-imply-the-funct)